# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. in Facebook canvas

Tags: django, facebook, heroku, csrf, django-csrf

Ok, so as you can see I have a Django app going on using csrf. It all works perfectly but, now I want my app to be shown in a iframe (Facebook canvas).

While in my main domain it works, in the Facebook canvas I keep getting this error:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Reason given for failure:
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

I know I'm missing something, but right now I don't know what is it.

**Code:**

In settings.py I have this correctly:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '***************'
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET          = '********************************'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email','publish_actions']
```

---

I'm using Heroku and in my `heroku confing` in the `heroku toolbelt` I have `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_SECRET` also correctly set.

**More info:**

A friend, really long time ago (nearly two years ago) already had set a Facebook login and a Facebook register working in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help you: https://github.com/jjanssen/django-fb-iframe

> Django and Facebook do not get along. When embedding a microsite into Facebook it will call an iframe with a POST request. Of course your Django project will return a CSRF verification failed.
>
> This little Django app will prevent that specific error by converting
>   a POST request with the key signed_request to a GET request. Of course
>   this is just plain ugly, but Facebook should not mess with our
>   application.

Comment: You have any idea why this happens? -> sudo pip install django-fb-iframe
Downloading/unpacking django-fb-iframe
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-fb-iframe
No distributions at all found for django-fb-iframe

Comment: Well, somehow it's not at PyPi. But you can easily download or clone it from github.

Comment: this could explain why a POST from Mechanical Turk fails as well.